# How to index dataset using object-like syntax in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a ragged, multidimensional dataset (~100 gb) to analyze. The data was produced by evaluating various functions in turn, each relying on the output of the previous stage, and possibly some parameters. Therefore the dataset has some dimensions that are very small (those corresponding to the choice of function at a given nesting depth), and others much bigger (corresponding to parameter choices for the functions).

I feel it would be most natural to access values in this set using "object-like" syntax of the form:

```
foo(x1, y1).bar(c1).baz(d, e, f)
goo(x2, y2).ber(c2).baz(d, e, h)
...
```

or similar. This mimics the way the data was produced (e.g. just as if I had used memoization when I originally generated the data).

What is the simplest or most efficient way (I realize these are not the same, but I am interested in both) to do this in Python? I realize this is a cosmetic issue, but I feel it will have a big impact on ease of use in my intended application.

Comment: Not even sure if ZODB will scale to 100GB, but take a look at http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/, if you really want to do things using that object-like syntax.  Although really, I would try to figure out the relationships of the data and either use a RDBMS or a graph database (virtuoso, neo4j) to analyze or whatever, depending on what needs to be done.

Comment: Reminds me of the introspection magic the Python implementation of Google Protocol Buffers uses. Maybe a look at what they did can help you get some ideas: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial and https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks! The description under "Why Use Protocol Buffers?" sounds a lot like my problem. I'll take a closer look.